# how to call platform specific page from xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am new to the xamarin app development, I have some questions :

1. Is it possible to call the platform specific page from the
   Xamarin.Form page?
2. Can I do Page Navigation from view model?

Let me explain clearly.

I have a Page `XFView.xaml` , `XFView.xaml.cs` and `XFViewModel.cs` in PCL (Xamarin.Forms) project from `XFView.xaml.cs` or  `XFViewModel.cs` i want to call `MAActivity.cs` page which is present in `Xamarin.Andriod` project

I tried a lot but got getting any idea.

Answer (score 11):

Whenever you would like to call something from native (`MAActivity.cs` in your case), you have to use DependencyService.

For example:

1. Setup dependency service

   ```
   // PCL Project
   public interface INativePages
   {
       void StartMA();
   }

   // MonoDroid Project
   [assembly: Dependency(typeof(NativePages))]

   public class NativePages : INativePages
   {
       public void StartMA()
       {
           var intent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(MAActivity));
           Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Invoke in PCL

   ```
   // PCL Project
   DependencyService.Get<INativePages>().StartMA();
   ```

Comment: This works well for Android - but I'm struggling to find the WP8 equivalent. There seem to be some solutions involving custom renders, but I'd prefer to avoid that...

Comment: Got it! 
            `(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(new Uri("/PageName.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`