# Why can't I put [assembly:Dependency()] above a class?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement some platform-specific code in Xamarin, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688133/how-to-call-platform-specific-page-from-xamarin-forms), but I ran into an issue with setting the platform-specific class to a Dependency. I get the following compiler error, underlined the `assembly` word of the tag:

> Assembly and module attributes must precede all other elements defined in a file except using clauses and extern alias declarations.

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Permissions;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp_Xamarin.Droid {
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(View.ActualPage.BarcodeScannerTest))]
public class BarcodeScannerTestClass : View.ActualPage.BarcodeScannerTest
{
    public async void Start(INavigation nav, Page page)
    {
        var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();

        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            // Stop scanning
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            // Pop the page and show the result
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                nav.PopAsync();
                page.DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
            });
        };

        // Navigate to our scanner page
        await nav.PushAsync(scanPage);
    }
}
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have anything appearing above the code you've shown us? I'd expect, at the very least, for there to be some `using` declarations.

Comment: Is this snippet inside a namespace declaration? The assembly attribute would have to be applied outside that.

Comment: I've added the `namespace` and `using` declarations from the code.

Comment: In that error message, do you see any mention of namespace declarations, in the list of things that are allowed to precede assembly and module attributes? If not, why do you think you're allowed to have one here?

Comment: So that "namespace MyApp_Xamarin.Droid" is one of the "elements" that the error is talking about. The attribute declaration has to be moved before that.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! You should put it in an answer so I can mark it as such. (I also now encountered a different exception, should I put it as a new question, or put it here? Seems to be a bit unrelated)

Comment: @Exec - new questions go into new questions. **If** they're related, you may want to link back to the previous one. But also, (I'm going to sound a bit harsh here) make sure that your next question isn't answered by carefully reading the error message you've already been given.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the error says the assembly attribute has to be declared before most other program elements in the file. The namespace declaration (`namespace MyApp_Xamarin.Droid`) is one of these elements. You have to move the attribute before that:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(View.ActualPage.BarcodeScannerTest))]

namespace MyApp_Xamarin.Droid 
{
    public class BarcodeScannerTestClass : View.ActualPage.BarcodeScannerTest
```

Answer (score 0):

**issue with setting the platform-specific class to a Dependency For Entry or Any Controller.**

```
 I get the following compiler error, underlined the assembly word of the tag:
```

**Assembly and module attributes must precede all other elements defined in a file except using clauses and extern alias declarations.**

```
using CustomrendersAll.customRenders;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CustomrendersAll.Droid.customRenders
{
 [assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(MyEntry), typeof(customRenderAndriod))]
    public class customRenderAndriod : EntryRenderer
    {  
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);

                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);

                }
            }

    }
}
```

Above Some mistake is there below code to Is correct

```
using CustomrendersAll.customRenders;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using CustomrendersAll.Droid.customRenders;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(customRenderAndriod))]
namespace CustomrendersAll.Droid.customRenders
{
    public class customRenderAndriod : EntryRenderer
    {  
            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);

                }
            }

    }
}
```

Before Class is not correct way 1st code is i wrote class way assembly  this code is

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Pclclass), typeof(customRenderAndriod))]
```

Before namespace 2nd code adding assembly  this code is

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Pclclass), typeof(customRenderAndriod))]
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to use

using System;using System.Reflection;using System.Security.Permissions;

Comment: Why should he try using what you suggest?

Comment: Tried, did not work, but the code doen't even use it (greyed out).

Comment: Assembly means dll or exe.. you can use using if you want to use existing dll or must check dll compatibily from your OS.